# Should you ever correct anyone, when it actually matters?

Tags: company-culture, meetings, discrimination

Should you ever correct other people when they make significant mistakes in an enviroment without customers (ie. relevants amounts of time would be wasted or whole projects fail)?

If you have to do you so frequently, can you do it without coming across as arrogant?

Do you have to make mistakes just to not piss off people?

Should you change the company if people get pissed off by your correctness?

Assuming that the comments were appropriate and relevant in the first place (ie. not smartass comments that barely made an impact/are trivial and not signifcant difference to what was said, but only relevant topics that spared the company/workers 16 or more hours of unnecessary work or prevented huge mistakes).

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful, I am glad that you edited out the "100%." I do believe that correcting people is necessary, but you have to do it in a way that wins cooperation  and respect. This is _exactly_ what behavioral interviews look for in questions which ask about how you deal with disagreements. Reflect upon the most successful and inspiring leaders that you've known and recall how they handled situations where someone on their team was "wrong." The question is not "whether or not to correct people" but rather "how to correct people." That said, I am sure it has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mistakes impact on your tasks then yes, you should bring them up in a professional manner to management. There is nothing arrogant about this, it's normal professionalism.

If the mistakes do not impact on your tasks or responsibilities then there is no need to rock the boat.

In an environment where you feel things are falling apart it is safest to just concentrate on fulfilling your own tasks and responsibilities and covering your back rather than getting involved with other peoples problems, there is no positive side to it for you although it may benefit the company.There are already people being paid (probably much more than you) to recognise these issues and rectify them.

If you cannot fit into the company it's best to move on and take what you can from it as a learning experience.